# Java, How to hardcode an array into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to create an ArrayList of type product

How do I insert an array into the ArrayList?

```
public Inventory()
{
    products = new ArrayList<ProductLine>();
    products.add(new ProductLine("A0001", 10.90, 9.90, 100, "N/A"));
    products.add(new ProductLine("B0010", 12.00, 7.50, 125, "5"));
    products.add(new ProductLine("C0100", 3.00, 2.30, 1000, "16"));
    products.add(new ItemisedProductLine("D1000", 2600, 2490, 2, Arrays.asList("a b d", "e f g h", "i j k l"))));
    products.add(new ProductLine("E0001", 699, 509, 3, Arrays.asList(new serialNumbers("CCCC333333"),new serialNumbers("DDDD444444"), new serialNumber("AAAA222222"))));
}
```

I get an error:

```
"missing ';' 
expecting ')'...")
```

What is the proper way to hardcode an array into an ArrayList?

Comment: Post the declaration of the `ItemisedProductLine` and `ProductLine` constructors. in itself your code is fine.

Comment: apart from the too many closing Parentheses on the ItemisedProductLine line

Comment: OP, please convince us that you are not abusing us to balance your parens for you.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't there an extra ")" at the end of line 7?

Comment: Let's hope he's not alerting SO about ONE EXTRA PAREN!

Comment: Hmm, checked. You're right :) I hate those (((( and )))), always confusing me! xD

Comment: embarrassing!!! i really need a break. You guys actually right, now it complains about something in my ItemisedProductLine class.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, i spent quite a bit of time on that(better i don't say how much...):-)